# MKMapView in cell crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a map view in a custom cell.
I create the cell and delegate like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //mapview
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MapCell";
    MapCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Map delegate
    cell.mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

It works fine, but sometimes in crashlytics, crash appears with the following log:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread                     0  libobjc.A.dylib            
0x389478f8 _objc_trap() + 18446744073709552000              1  libobjc.A.dylib     
0x3894795d _objc_inform                                     2  libobjc.A.dylib            
0x389563cb weak_register_no_lock + 182                      3  libobjc.A.dylib               
0x389566ff objc_storeWeak + 110                             4  MapKit                        
0x2f3d6fdd -[MKMapView(MKNonARC) setDelegate:] + 160        5  PTV Truck     
0x0013e63f -[DetailParkingViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (DetailParkingViewController.m:771)  6  UIKit
0x30b15199 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 408           7  UIKit
0x30abc3fb -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1802    8  UIKit
0x30b00caf -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 142      9  PTV Truck   
0x00147d7b -[DetailParkingViewController dealloc] (DetailParkingViewController.m:1867)                            10 libsystem_blocks.dylib        
0x38e62ac5 _Block_release + 216                             11 libdispatch.dylib             
0x38e30d3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22                    12 libdispatch.dylib         
0x38e336c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278          13 CoreFoundation  
0x2e17d679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8  14 CoreFoundation
0x2e17bf45 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308                            15 CoreFoundation
0x2e0e67a9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524                       16 CoreFoundation
0x2e0e658b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106                         17 GraphicsServices
0x330536d3 GSEventRunModal + 138                            18 UIKit
0x30a45891 UIApplicationMain + 1136                         19 PTV Truck
0x000b7037 main (main.m:16)
```

I have no idea why the crash occurs sometimes for some users...
Crashlytics says it occurs in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
0x30b00caf -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 142 9 PTV Truck
0x00147d7b -[DetailParkingViewController dealloc] (DetailParkingViewController.m:1867) 10 libsystem_blocks.dylib
```

It looks like you're calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: in your dealloc method of your view controller. Generally, calling anything from there is dangerous, but this particular issue is because setting a weak reference (the map view's delegate) to a deallocating object is not allowed. I would stop calling this method from your dealloc.

If you're calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: to get the cell in order to nil out its delegate,  there's no need to do this; since the delegate is weak, it'll be cleared out automatically.